# php echo html and php code

Tags: php, html, echo

How can you add this line of code in a

```
<a href='/<?=$value["content_url"];?>' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><?=$value["content_title"];?><span class="caret"></span></a>
```

so eventually you get something like this:

```
if (1 == 1) { 
    echo "<a href='/<?=$value["content_url"];?>' 
    class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" 
    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> <?=$value["content_title"];?>
    <span class="caret"></span></a>";
} else { 
    echo "Nothing to see!" 
}
```

Because you have multiple punctuations it will end the echo to quick..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format your string properly. Updated string.

```
if (1 == 1) { 
    echo "<a href=\"$value[content_url]\"  
    class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" role=\"button\"  
    aria-haspopup=\"true\" aria-expanded=\"true\">$value[content_title] 
    <span class=\"caret\"></span></a>";
} else { 
    echo "Nothing to see!"; 
}
```

Inside double quoted string the php variables don't need to be quoted. Escape quotes by a backslash.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Did not know that you could remove the punctuations in the variables.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to actually print the PHP-code, you just have to escale your quotes

```
echo "<a href='/<?=$value[\"content_url\"];?>' class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" role=\"button\" aria-haspopup=\"true\" aria-expanded=\"true\"><?=$value[\"content_title\"];?><span class=\"caret\"></span></a>";
```

if instead you want to print the values, you do not need the tags at all, but just have to concatenate the variables.

```
echo "<a href='/".
$value["content_url"].
"' class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" role=\"button\" aria-haspopup=\"true\" aria-expanded=\"true\">".
$value["content_title"].
"<span class=\"caret\"></span></a>";
```

Comment: Bad example. At least run the code on your end first before suggesting.

Comment: oops, sorry. my bad. won't happen again

Comment: Mistakes happen... Big world.. bad thing is someone rated your answer up and not yet mine.. lolz

Answer (score 0):

```
if you want to print or echo php code than use concatenate    

if (1 == 1) { 
        echo "<a href='".$value["content_url"]."' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button' 
        aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='true'> '".$value["content_title"]."' <span class='caret'></span></a>";
    } else { 
        echo "Nothing to see!" 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='<?php  echo  $value["content_url"]; ?>' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
<?php echo $value["content_title"]; ?>
   <span class="caret"></span> 
</a>
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

You can use print_f() function:

```
print_f("<a href='%s' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='true'><span class='caret'>%s</span></a>",
  $value['content_url'],
  $value['content_title']
);
```

or echo string in "string {var}":

```
echo "
   <a href='{$value['content_url']}' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='true'><span class='caret'>{$value['content_title']}</span></a>
" ;
```

or use concritenate operand . 'string 1'.'string 2'

```
echo '
   <a href="'.$value['content_url'].'" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><span class="caret">'.$value['content_title'].'</span></a>
' ;
```

but best way use template for example

index.php

```
function getContentUrl() {
   return $value['content_url'];
}

function getTitle() {
   return $value['content_title'];
}

include './template.phtml';
```

and template.phtml

```
<a href='<?php echo getContentUrl() ?>'><?php echo getContentTitle() ?></a>
```